# Saving list of Safari tabs and their windows in corresponding order as .txt file. Solution found but need to edit it to work as desired

Tags: applescript, safari

How can I amend the AppleScript from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389110 to save each windows tabs into a text file sperated by a space and repeat for each remaining windows? Same applies for when I want to open them, I would like to open them in same order/tabs/Windows that I saved them in and not all complied into one Window.

Comment: This site works better with one question per post, you can always ask the other question separately. Also, what have you tried already to solve this yourself?

Comment: Sorry about that, new to Ask Different. I don't have the knowledge to solve it, as I currently still learning and came across the answer from Googling.